# Detecting when serial RX goes idle between data packets

Tags: serial-port

I'm running an ARM-based computer that receives data from an external device via serial. The external device alternates between bursts of data and idling: 25 bytes, then 3ms idle, 25 bytes, 3ms idle, and so on. However, every so ofter it drops a byte in the middle of the packet and only outputs 24 bytes. Because of the slight inconsistency, I'm trying to figure out a way to detect when the line goes idle so I can be confident that I'm processing at the beginning of the next packet.

The packet does use start and stop bytes, 0xF0 and 0x00, but they are not unique. A 0xF0 or 0x00 may arrive as data in the middle of the packet as well without any special handling. I believe detecting 3ms of idle followed by a start byte is the only way to be certain a new packet is arriving.

Is there a way in Linux to detect the idle line and synchronize to the beginning of a new packet this way? I'm coding primarily in C using open() and read() on the serial port, but a shell script would work too.